# How can I turn off Emacs's auto line wrapping for the current session?

Tags: emacs

How can I turn off Emacs's auto line wrapping for the current session?

I normally need the automatic wrapping, but when editing a email draft, I don't need that. Is there a way to turn it off for a while?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Depending on which flavor of automatic line wrapping you're using, it'll be one of

```
M-x toggle-truncate-lines
```

if your lines wrap hard at the right-hand edge of the window, or

```
M-x visual-line-mode
```

if your lines "soft wrap" at the whitespace nearest the right-hand edge of the window.

(If you're using an Emacs version older than 24.4, it may also be `M-x longlines-mode`, if your lines wrap hard at a given column.)

If you've issued the wrong command for your configuration, then the message in the minibuffer will say "...enabled" instead of "...disabled"; in that case, just issue the same command again to re-disable the bogus mode, and try the others until you've found the one which disables the mode you're actually using.

These are buffer-local modes, so issuing the command will affect only the buffer you're in when you do so; in all other buffers, you'll still have the benefit of line wrapping unless you similarly turn off the mode there as well.

Should you wish later to turn line-wrapping back on, just reissue the command you used to disable it.

Comment: For another culprit implicated in visual line wrapping, try `M-x toggle-truncate-lines`

Comment: @BarryKelly Good point! I'd forgotten about that one -- I've just edited the answer to include it.

Comment: I use it often enough to bind it to a keyboard shortcut by adding `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c w") 'toggle-truncate-lines); wrap` in my .emacs file.

Comment: In recent Emacs `toggle-truncate-lines` is bound to `C-x x t`

Answer (score 14):

Another possibility may be to toggle `auto-fill-mode`: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, *auto-fill-mode* (tab completion works)

For example, turning off `auto-fill-mode` in [AUCTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUCTeX) stops hard line wrapping

Comment: This is the right answer for LaTeX modes.

Comment: It works for me in all sorts of modes, including text mode.

Answer (score 12):

Just an update on `longlines-mode`.

As of Emacs 24.4, `longlines-mode` no longer exists. Therefore I'd recommend using `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` if you want it temporarily, or `(set-default 'truncate-lines t)` in your `.emacs` file if you want it be default in all buffers

Comment: I need this effect for the *current* buffer, or editing session, and in particular, not as a default.

Comment: Ah right, misread the initial question. Just wanted to provide an update that `longlines-mode` won't work anymore. Updated my answer

Comment: This was the only - and also most painless - solution that worked for me. @qazwsx consider changing this to the accepted one?

Comment: Yes, this works in the current document (Alt + X, toggle-truncate-lines).